# Alt+M to merge vertices is not working anymore

Tags: modeling, vertices, shortcut

I'm trying to merge vertices using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> keyboard shortcut, but instead I get an option to split. I never saw this menu before
Please help.

[image]

Comment: If you can't find the keyboard shortcut for something, you can access the search menu with f3, type in the name of the function, and it'll give you the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new shortcut to merge is <kbd>M</kbd>.

No <kbd>Alt</kbd> is needed no more.

You can use the right mouse button to bring up the **Context Menu**, and the shortcuts should be visible there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! OMG, I've been using 2.8 for a while I guess this is the first time I used the merge vertex function.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> before <kbd>M</kbd>.
Simply go to *3D view* window. Press hotkey <kbd>M</kbd> and select your merge choice.

Here's something new about Merge: If you ever want to remove doubles before rendering, it is now hotkey <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge > By Distance*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just press <kbd>F</kbd> between 2 selected vertices. It will automatically fill a line. Once they are connected by a line, select 3 or more vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd> once again to fill it.